# Periodic input to Windows gitbash terminal

Tags: windows, mingw, git-bash, mintty, stty

My bash terminal is receiving a space (chr 32) immediately followed by a backspace (chr 8) every 5 seconds (almost exactly). The effects aren't noticeable when typing, as the added space is deleted within a few milliseconds, however it does have other more obvious and annoying side effects. For example, when paging through a file via `less`, the space makes it automatically page through once every 5 seconds. This among other things is making it difficult to work, and I cant figure out why it's happening.

I'm on Windows 7, using git via the gitbash terminal that comes as part of the packaged download from git-scm.com.

I get the same behavior when just running the `mintty.exe` program that gets placed in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`. I've made sure to empty my `.bashrc`.
I've also tried restarting, as well as uninstalling and re-installing.
Also worth noting, the behavior continues even if the terminal is not the active focused window.

The issue has only started recently, but I can't think of any change made to my system that would cause this. Does anyone know what might cause this 5-second repeated ghost-input I'm seeing. Alternatively, how might I be able to track down where the input is coming from?

Comment: Do you have a similar behaviour in e.g. cmd and Powershell?

Comment: @simlev, no. Only the mingw/mintty bash window. Actually, every bash window, if there's more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, this is some conflict resulting from your `PATH`. E.g. here, I'm getting an error at startup because `/etc/bash.bashrc` is looking for `getent` which is absent from Git's MSYS but is present in Cygwin which I have further in `PATH`.

`.bashrc` is not the only automatically parsed file. [There's also](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, `/etc/bash.*` and `~/.bash*`.

To localize the problem,

- rename `c:\Program Files\Git\etc` to exclude startup files *and* any other behaviour-altering files like `/etc/inputrc`. If the problem persists, look for the reason in loaded modules' list (can be viewed with `procexp`).
- run `bash -i --noprofile --norc` to disable just the startup files.
- rename individual startup files/folders (half the amount at a time [to pinpoint the culprit with logarithmic number of steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)).

Comment: I had some trouble using the `--noprofile` and `--norc` flags, but I did try renaming the /etc  directory. Unfortunately, despite a few error messages related to not finding /etc, the issue I'm having was still present

Comment: @wutch if the issue is present even without any startup files, then, as I wrote, it's either some module being loaded from a wrong location, or some other installed software injects itself into the process, or some program running in background sends keystrokes to the window.